# Azure Stream Analytics - User Verification

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have data in an Event Hub which i'm passing to an Azure SQL Server database via a Stream Analytics job. I've had it working, but now when i start the job i get a 'Login failed for user xxx'.

I can log into the database and make changes etc using Azure Data Studio or via the Azure portal, but when i try to test the Output connection or run the job, it fails with the above error. The user exists and has admin access etc. Anyone seen this before ?

Thanks in advance

JC

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to contain more specifics. Right now, it's really difficult to pinpoint what's happening. Also: have you attempted to re-configure your Stream Analytics output connection to your SQL Database? Did you confirm that your SQL Database firewall is properly set up to allow your Stream Analytics job to connect to it? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is generally caused by the firewall, so first check the firewall of your sql server.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxgJc.png)